# To read the contents of a table that is RFC disabled

Tags: saprfc

Is there any functional module through which we can read the table contents which is not a RFC enabled? There's a table which is RFC disabled and I need to access the contents using RFC... RFC_READ_TABLE isn't working in this case...

Comment: is there an RFC flag for tables? I can see none in SE11. Which table are you trying to access?

Answer (score 1):

RFC_READ_TABLE has a few limitations, for example it does not support unicode and it has problems with binary data and some datatypes like FLTP. SAP published a note (note # 758278) to either repair the function module RFC_READ_TABLE or copy it and modify your customer copy.

Answer (score 0):

RFC_READ_TABLE is mostly used for generic reading of "any" table (with noted limitations).  If you have a specific requirement, you might be more successful with a specifically designed (rfc enabled) function module that returns exactly what you need.  This would give you the opportunity to provide a more strongly typed dataset (so you could get something back with actual columns, not just a big text structure that has to be parsed).